# How to post json data to wcf service

Tags: json, wcf

how to post call SaveCorporateProfile function by passing json

```
[DataContract]
public class myclass
{
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}



 [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICustProfileService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/SaveCorporateProfile?dt={dt}")]
        string SaveCorporateProfile(myclass dt);
    }

public string SaveCorporateProfile(myclass dt)
        {          

            return "success";
        }
```

Comment: Is this what you are after?  [Here is a link to a possible solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392600/wcf-how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-in-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this;

Firstly, you should edit your *myclass* like this;

```
[DataContract]
public class myclass
{

    [DataMember]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

then your interface like this;

```
 [ServiceContract]
public interface ICustProfileService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string SaveCorporateProfile(myclass dt);
}
```

And you implement your .svc file for using this interface

```
 public class CustProfileService: ICustProfileService
{
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",UriTemplate = "/SaveCorporateProfile?dt={dt}"
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]

    public string SaveCorporateProfile(myclass dt)
    {          

        return "success";
    }

}
```